# Difference between saved/load json object in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem saving a json object in mongodb(Mongoose) so when i make the insert everything is ok, but when i make the request of the same object, Mongoose return a modified json. Its like Mongoose autocomplete the twitter field and i dont know why.

Here is my code:

```
UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
firstName:  String,
lastName:   String,
email:      String,
salt:       String,
hash:       String,
twitter:{
    id:       String,
    email:    String,
    name:     String
},
facebook:{
    id:       String,
    email:    String,
    name:     String,
    username: String,
    photo:    String,
    gender:   String
}
});
```

I save json in my database:

```
User.create({
        email : profile.emails[0].value,
        facebook : {
            id:    profile.id,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            name:  profile.displayName,
            username: profile.username,
            photo: profile.photos[0].value,
            gender: profile.gender
            }
        }, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            // if (err) return done(err);
            done(null, user);
        });
```

But i when mongoose return a json.

[image]

Mongoose generated a field in the json. twitter:{}  <----

I dont know why, can anyone lend me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the document saved to the MongoDB, you'll see that the `twitter` object isn't actually present unless the properties of the sub object are set. The object is created so that you can conveniently set properties without needing to worry about creating the sub/nested object. So you can do this:

```
var user = new User();
user.twitter.id = 'wiredprairie';
user.save();
```

Results:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("522259394eb9ed0c30000002"), 
  "twitter" : { "id" : "wiredprairie" }, "__v" : 0 }
```

And if you went one step further and wanted a more "pure" view of the data, you could use `toJSON` on the Mongoose model instance:

```
console.log(user.toJSON());
```

results:

```
{ _id: 522259ad3621834411000001, twitter: { id: 'wiredprairie' } }
```

Comment: I resolved the problem with your answer, i used toJSON function and its work fine. Thanks